# How to change the default app icon in the Facebook login authentication screen

Tags: android, ios, iphone, facebook, authentication

Plain and simple. I need to change the default app icon that is presented to the user when in the authentication screen when logging into the app using the Facebook SDK.

[image]

**What I have tried:**

**`www.developer.facebook.com -> My Apps -> App Details -> Icons`**

Any help is appreciated! Thank you for your time!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @derabbink I have already tried fixing it using the website and it doesn't work, so that would suggest that its done programmatically.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately seems that it's not possible to customize the gear icon.

As stated by a member of Facebook Team on [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/317451798411754/):

> This is by design. The confirmation dialog does not serve the app
>   icon, but instead uses an non-app specific icon.

Comment: This is a correct answer. I tried to fix the same issue but ended up leaving it as it is

Comment: @Mattia Thanks. There actually used to be a way to change it, but they have apparently removed that option.

Answer (score 3):

**@Alexander of Norway** . Sorry, your own custom (icon)screen is not supported by **Facebook**.
*Actually*

```
facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
```

***Method call will present the following dialog box to the user:***

[image]

For more information check out the [Social Integration section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android) in  ***Android documentation***.

### This is how facebook authorization process will work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to change that icon.

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/
2. From My apps choose your app
3. Now from left hand side under settings menu click on basic.
4. Now you will see this option "App Icon (1024 x 1024)".
5. Upload your app icon and click on save changes.
6. Restart your app and try to login with facebook now.